# I want to redirect and rewrite my urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop-single-full.php?img=35
```

I want to rewrite and redirect this url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Pure-Copper-Embossed-Jug-amp-4-Steel-Copper-Glass-Set-35.html
```

where text is the product name.
I also want when someone want to access

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop-single-full.php?img=35
```

it will automatically redirect it to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Pure-Copper-Embossed-Jug-amp-4-Steel-Copper-Glass-Set-35.html
```

Whatever I have tried is

```
RewriteRule ^shop-single-full/?$ ([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\-([0-9]+).html?%1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\-([0-9]+).html?$ /shop-single-full.php?img=$2&name=$1
```

but there is some problem in redirection.Thanks

Comment: Will different img ID's have different url names? Like `?img=10 => /some_product-10.html`, `?img=20 => /another_product-20.html`? In that case, you need to do it in your code, not with rewrite, since you need to fetch the name by it's ID somehow. Unless you want to define them all in your rewrite rules?

Comment: Btw.. you say _"I also want..."_ and then you explain the exact same thing again?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that's different from each other.If some try to open ugly url it should not open and redirect it to pretty url.(I am talking in that case where url rewriting has been done but not redirecting)

Comment: Please update and phrase your question(s) more clearly. You actually say that you want to redirect in both cases. First: (rewrite and redirect) and second: (automatically redirect to). I can't see any real difference. Rewrite can't change the URL without redirecting it...  Look at the marked answer here for a more indepth explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: at this time i just want to redirect my urls like /shop-single-full.php?img=10 & name=some-product =>  /some-product-10.html because i have done url rewriting.Please update a solution for doing this in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `header()` in `shop-single-full.php`

```
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/Pure-Copper-Embossed-Jug-amp-4-Steel-Copper-Glass-Set-35.html");
```

Read more about `header()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: i just want to block /shop-single-full.php in htaccess with /Pure-Copper-Embossed-Jug-amp-4-Steel-Copper-Glass-Set-35.html what can i do for that??